# Implements of android P Prevent Idle Background Apps from Accessing the Camera

Tags: android, android-source

I saw this news [say android P Prevent Idle Background Apps from Accessing the Camera](https://www.xda-developers.com/android-p-background-apps-camera/), And dive into Android Open Source Project (AOSP) [link](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/system/sepolicy/+/588493) only seen this commit only modified the selinux(te) file, And curious about how it works, anyone could give me more details about this ?

1. Whether there are some codes relevant to this feature is close sourced? (since I watched the repository [platform/frameworks/av](https://android-review.googlesource.com/admin/repos/platform/frameworks/av) but found nothing about what I think is doing with this feature, also I searched AOSP with keyword camera but found nothing.
2. Any clue about How could I know how this feature works?

Comment: @Madcode I guess It works with the Doze mode, which I think it couldn't  protect the camera with all cases (eg, In some countries, For some reason Doze mode was mostly disabled)